# How to realize a 3d web Applet

Tags: silverlight, apache-flex, 3d

i've been request from a customer to realize a 3d applet (maybe flex or silverlight ?) that gives me the possibility to apply clothes textures (such as pants or shoes) to human 3d models.

I also need to modify the height of the models...

can you give me any suggestion about where to start ? i'm pretty new in this world and i need a way to start from scratch.

Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 3):

Does he need "True" 3D or Faux 3D?

For true 3D in the Flash Player, you'll need to use Stage3D which is only available in [prerelease form from Adobe Labs](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashplatformruntimes/incubator/).  I expect it in the next major version of the Flash Player.  If I had to guess that will be Version 11 and it will be released at Adobe Max in October.  If you Google around, the code name was called Molehill.  You may find some videos and other information on it using that name.

If "Faux" 3D is okay, then there are a handful of frameworks for Flash you canlook at, such as [Away3D](http://away3d.com/) or [PaperVision](http://blog.papervision3d.org/).

I can't help w/ regards to Silverlight specifics.

---

Update:

PaperVision is an abandoned product, as pointed out in the comments, so I would only use that with caution.

[Alternativa](http://alternativaplatform.com/en/) is another alternative.

Comment: I would vote against Papervision since it hasn't been worked on in years.  The 2 main choices are Away3D and Alternativa.

Comment: @J_A_X I'll take your word for it; I don't keep up on the Frameworks.  I thought Alternativa was built on top of Stage3D.  They were at the last Max giving out Molehill T-shirts.

Comment: Looking at the Alternativa site; it appears they are not tied to Flash Player's Stage3D technology.  I added a link to them in my answer.

Comment: Away3D and Alternativa are the two most worked on currently.  They both have a Stage3D version and a non Stage3D version (just need to switch out the renderer which is easy enough).  Of course, both are pushing hard for Molehill.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to use [Silverlight](http://www.silverlight.net/), than you clients can run your application only on Windows and Mac. If it's OK for you than take a look to this frameworks:

- [Balder](http://balder.codeplex.com/)
- [Kit3D](http://kit3d.codeplex.com/)
- [Postvision](http://www.postvision.net/SilverMotion/Demos.aspx)

Olso you can use new 3D engine for [Silverlight 5](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/MED06), which is on beta, but avaliable only for Windows OS.

Comment: +1 for providing the Silverlight info that I didn't know in my own answer.